# Create Jordan matrix from eigenvalues using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have *ndarray* of eigenvalues and their multiplicities (for instance, `np.array([(2.2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 1)])`). I need to compute Jordan matrix for this eigenvalues without using Python cycles and iterables (list comprehensions, `for` loops etc.), only by using *NumPy*'s functions.

I decided to build the matrix by this steps:

1. Create this blocks using `np.vectorize` and `np.eye` with `np.fill_diagonal`:

[image: Parts]

2. Combine blocks into one matrix using `hstack` and `vstack`.

But I've got two problems:

1. Here's snippet of my block creating code:

```
def eye(t):
    eye = np.eye(t[1].astype(int),k=1)
    return eye

def jordan_matrix(X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    dim = np.sum(X[:,1].astype(int))
    eyes = np.vectorize(eye, signature='(x)->(n,m)')(X)
    return eyes
```

And I'm getting error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (2,2)`

2. I need to create extra zero matrices to fill space which is not used by created blocks, but their sizes are variable and I can't figure out how to create them without using Python's `for` and its equivalents.

Am I on the right way? How can I get out of this problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
def jordan(a):
    e = a[:,0]  # eigenvalues
    m = a[:,1].astype('int')  # multiplicities
    d = np.repeat(e, m) # main diagonal
    ones = np.ones(d.size - 1)
    ones[np.cumsum(m)[:-1] -1] = 0
    j = np.diag(d) + np.diag(ones, k=1)
    return j
```

Edit: just realized that my solution is almost the same as Divakar's.

Answer (score 4):

`np.vectorize` would basically loop under the hoods. We could use NumPy funcs for actual vectorization at Python level. Here's one such way -

```
def blockwise_jordan(a):
    r = a[:,1].astype(int)
    v = np.repeat(a[:,0],r)
    out = np.diag(v)
    n = out.shape[1]

    fillvals = np.ones(n, dtype=out.dtype)
    fillvals[r[:-1].cumsum()-1] = 0
    out.flat[1::out.shape[1]+1] = fillvals
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [52]: X = np.array([(2.2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 1)])

In [53]: blockwise_jordan(X)
Out[53]: 
array([[2.2, 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 2.2, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 3. , 1. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 3. , 1. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 3. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 5. ]])
```

**Optimization #1**

We can replace the final three steps to perform the conditional assignment of 1s and 0s, like so -

```
out.flat[1::n+1] = 1
c = r[:-1].cumsum()-1
out[c,c+1] = 0
```

Comment: Upvote! I came up with almost the same solution, but a little bit later.

Comment: To be honest, everytime I wait for your answers to learn something new.

Comment: @Navaro You actually went through everything to understand? That's something!